# Need Help using IF/OR/AND formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

All.

I am trying to use IF/OR/AND formula for the below conditions.

1. If S = 0, then use the lowest of M and F, provided both M and F has a value which is greater than 0. If either one in M and F is zero then take the one in M and F which is greater than zero.
2. If all S,M and F is Zero, then it should show zero.
3. If M and F has a value which is greater than S, even then it should use the value which is in S, provided S is greater than 0.
4. In the Final Value column - It should show me the the value of S, provided the value of S is greater than Zero or the value from condition 1.

Please note: I do not require all the condition to be satisfied in one single formula. There can be multiple columns to fulfill these conditions.

I am attaching a spreadsheet where i have these conditions. Also, i have tried using formula. Please feel free to create and new tab and work on it.

Link for the excel file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B403VWJ4ZXfoRDNGdUNCSVNkMWc

Thank you very much!

Comment: `=IF(S1>0,S1,IF(AND(M1>0,F1>0),MIN(M1,F1),MAX(0,M1,F1)))`?

Comment: No. It did not work. I think you have mistaken S as the cell. Can you please re-check ? Kindly look into the excel sheet.

Comment: What is `S` if it isn't the column?  (If that potentially virus-infected link in your question actually includes something relevant, please include the information in the question itself.  Otherwise you risk people downvoting your question.)

Comment: 1. You may be able to vastly reduce the number of conditions in the formula if it was known whether S, M or F could be less than zero. 2. Does your excel version support the newer MINIF and MAXIF worksheet functions?

Comment: @Jeeped - I did not reduce the conditions. I added more columns to test them individually. I figured it out myself and yes, i used max and min function to derive the final value.. Thank you!

Comment: @YowE3K I figured it out myself. I have a anti-virus which protects and that's what i thought that people also has and that is why i attached the excel sheet. Anyways thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula of

```
=IF(S1>0,S1,IF(AND(M1>0,F1>0),MIN(M1,F1),MAX(0,M1,F1)))
```

will:

- take S if it is greater than 0
- else

  - if both M and F are greater than 0, the smaller of the two
  - else (i.e. if one, or both, is not greater than 0) the maximum of the two

---

Judging by the other answers, I assume that (despite not being stated in the question) the mapping from letters used in your question to columns in your spreadsheet is actually

```
S --> A
M --> B
F --> C
```

so using that mapping and applying it to the formula gives

```
=IF(A1>0,A1,IF(AND(B1>0,C1>0),MIN(B1,C1),MAX(0,B1,C1)))
```

or, if your data starts in row 2 (also not mentioned in your question):

```
=IF(A2>0,A2,IF(AND(B2>0,C2>0),MIN(B2,C2),MAX(0,B2,C2)))
```

Comment: Thank you.. your '=IF(A2>0,A2,IF(AND(B2>0,C2>0),MIN(B2,C2),MAX(0,B2,C2)))' works!

Though i have already figured myself as i wanted to show the calculations in separate columns. But now i tried your formula and it matches with my formula's answer.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Answer will be as

```
= IF (A2=0, MIN( IF(B2>0,B2,0), IF(C2>0, C2, 0) ), IF(A2=0&B2=0&C2=0,0, IF(B2>A2&C2>A2,IF(A2>0, A2, 0),0 ) ) )
```

Step by step is shown below
[image]

Comment: Thank you.. But it looks like it is throwing up a wrong answer..
Please see the new spreadsheet that i am attaching, i have used your formula and also i have tried mine. please see if i am correct.
[link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B403VWJ4ZXfoMWdZWk1hMDYyaVU)

Comment: 1. Step if S != 0 what is the result?

Comment: Please give some examples with values because algorithms looks true.

Comment: What is the point of concatenating a `"0"` to `B2` in the part saying `0&B2`?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming Value of `S` will never be less than `0`, enter the following formula in `Cell D2`

```
=IF(A2=0,IF(B2>0,IF(C2>0,MIN(B2,C2),B2),IF(C2>0,C2,0)),IF(AND(B2>A2,C2>A2),A2,MIN(B2,C2)))
```

Drag/Copy down as required.

[image]